# Unable to use fgets function to read a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to take in multiple inputs(strings,integers and doubles) and add them to a linked list i cant get `fgets()` function to work properly and there's no constructive error that would help me find a solution.

I ask the user to enter each detail separately then try add it to a Linked List.
I realised that scanf doesn't work so tried to use fgets and it doesn't seem to work either.

```c
void add(){ 
  struct LinearNode *aNode;
    struct book *anElement;

    char *idB,*nameB,*authorB;
    int yearB,loanedTimesB;
    double valueB;

  anElement = (struct book *)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
  if (anElement == NULL)
            printf("Error - no space for the new element\n");
        else{
      printf("Please enter the book ID.\n");
      fgets(anElement->id,sizeof anElement->id,stdin);
      //strcpy(anElement->id, idB);
      printf("Please enter the name of the book.\n");
      scanf("%s", anElement->name);
      printf("Please enter the name of the book author.\n");
      scanf("%s", anElement->author);
      printf("Please enter the year of publication.\n");
      scanf("%d", &anElement->year);
      printf("Please enter the initial book value.\n");
      scanf("%lf", &anElement->value);
      anElement->loanedTimes = 0;
      anElement->loaned = false;

      aNode = (struct LinearNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinearNode));
      if (aNode == NULL)
                printf("Error - no space for the new node\n");
          else { // add data part to the node
                aNode->element = anElement;
                aNode->next = NULL;
                //add node to end of the list
                if (isEmpty()) {
                   front = aNode;
                   last = aNode;
                }
                else {
                     last->next = aNode;
                     last = aNode;
                  } //end else
           }
    }
}
```

here is the full code

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define bool int
#define false 0
#define true (!false)

//Libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
//Preprocessor Variable
#define SIZE 10

struct book{
  char *id,*name,*author;
  int year,loanedTimes;
  bool loaned;
  double value;
};

struct LinearNode {
    struct book *element;
    struct LinearNode *next;
};

struct LinearNode *front = NULL;
struct LinearNode *last = NULL;

void check(),menu(),add(),borrow(),returnBook(),deleteBook(),viewAll(),viewOne(),viewPopNo(),viewValue();
bool isEmpty();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    check();
  menu();
    return 0;
}

void check(){
  if( access( "book.dat", F_OK ) != -1 ) {
    printf("The system has been populated with books from the data file.\n");
} else {
    printf("Database of books doesn't exist.\nPlease populate it using the first function from the menu.\n");
}
}

void menu(){
    int x = 0;
    do{
    printf("1. Add a new book to the library \n");
    printf("2. Allow customer to take out a book \n");
    printf("3. Allow Customer to return a book \n");
    printf("4. Delete an old book from stock \n");
    printf("5. View all books \n");
    printf("6. View a specific book \n");
    printf("7. View details of most popular and least popular books \n");
    printf("8. Check value of the books \n");
    printf("9. Exit the system \n");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  getchar();
  if (x==1)
  add();
    }while(x!=9);
}
void add(){ 
  struct LinearNode *aNode;
    struct book *anElement;

    char *idB,*nameB,*authorB;
    int yearB,loanedTimesB;
    double valueB;

  anElement = (struct book *)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
  if (anElement == NULL)
            printf("Error - no space for the new element\n");
        else{
      printf("Please enter the book ID.\n");
      fgets(anElement->id,sizeof anElement->id,stdin);
      //strcpy(anElement->id, idB);
      printf("Please enter the name of the book.\n");
      scanf("%s", anElement->name);
      printf("Please enter the name of the book author.\n");
      scanf("%s", anElement->author);
      printf("Please enter the year of publication.\n");
      scanf("%d", &anElement->year);
      printf("Please enter the initial book value.\n");
      scanf("%lf", &anElement->value);
      anElement->loanedTimes = 0;
      anElement->loaned = false;

      aNode = (struct LinearNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinearNode));
      if (aNode == NULL)
                printf("Error - no space for the new node\n");
          else { // add data part to the node
                aNode->element = anElement;
                aNode->next = NULL;
                //add node to end of the list
                if (isEmpty()) {
                   front = aNode;
                   last = aNode;
                }
                else {
                     last->next = aNode;
                     last = aNode;
                  } //end else
           }
    }
}
bool isEmpty() {
    if (front == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Do not mix `fgets` with `scanf`. It will only give you troubles.

Comment: do you have any recommendations to take in strings and add them to a linked list?

Comment: You could use `getline` (or `fgets`) and `sscanf` to scan from the data you get from the first call.

Comment: What's `struct book`? Or more specifically what´s its field member `.id` (`sizeof anElement->id` may be wrong)?

Comment: `scanf` is not made for interactive user input. But you can use it for simple test programs. You can use `scanf("%s", anElement->id)` instead of `fgets`, as mentioned before, mixing `fgets` and `scanf` on the same input file only causes trouble.. Also show `struct book`, depending on how you've defined it, there may be other problems.

Comment: @xtreger There is a big problem in your code that became visible only once you've added the definition of `struct book`: `anElement = (struct book *)malloc(sizeof(struct book));`: after that, `anElement` points to a new `struct book`. but the individual pointers (`anElement->id`,  `anElement->name` and `anElement->author`) point nowhere, they are uninitialized pointers. You probably want rather something like: `struct book{
  char id[30], name[30], author[30];
...
};`

Comment: @Jabberwocky is this beeter?

```struct book{
  char id[10],name[30],author[30];
  int year,loanedTimes;
  bool loaned;
  double value;
};```

Comment: @xtreger please don't put code other than oneliners in a comment, as  you can see it is inreadable. Instead [edit]  your question.

Comment: @xtreger yes using arrays is OK, but pay attention to array index out of bounds problems. But I suppose you know that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof anElement->id` yields the size of a pointer!

```
fgets(anElement->id,sizeof anElement->id,stdin);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                  size of a pointer
//                  probably 4 or 8
```

You should allocate enough space and read that many bytes

```
anElement->id = malloc(100);      // error checking omitted for brevity
fgets(anElement->id, 100, stdin); // error checking omitted for brevity
// use anElement->id
free(anElement->id);
```

Don't forget to `free()` the memory when you no longer need it.

Comment: Does the ```free(anElement->id);``` clear then information saved in the linked list?
Because i still need it there.

Comment: After `free`ing it, you cannot access it anymore. I didn't take into consideration you are using a linked list. With a linked list you need to defer the `free` until you no longer need any of the list (probably the end of program). Some programmers simply don't even think about the resource usage in similar cases and just let the Operating System deal with that when the program terminates.

Comment: Maybe better for you to follow @Jabberwocky's suggestion and use arrays rather than pointers in your struct.